# Is it haram to cut family ties temporarily with a father who non-practicing?

Tags: halal-haram, family

My father is a Muslim however, he is no longer practicing. He also denounces key beliefs of Islam like fasting, salah, hijab and Islam as a way of life. He, in essence, hates Islam. He drinks and goes to clubs but still claims to be Muslim. Me and my 15 year old brother have not spoken to him in 4 years due to the fact he has admitted he wants to bring us down with him off the straight path of Islam. He is a very manipulative man and has already brought his cousin and sister down with him. He was also not good with my mother and cheated on her while they were married.

Is cutting him off the right decision for a vulnerable 15 year old boy. Or should the my brother remain in contact with him.

Comment: I don't think so. I seen to recall a story of companions being tortured by their non Muslim parents, while the prophet still taught them the values of family... I will look for references.

Comment: Maybe helpful http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/33229/is-it-wrong-to-sever-ties-of-kinship-in-the-case-of-an-abusive-relative

Answer (score 2):

**Praise be to Allah**
So, i just called a mufti specifically for this, as i also got curious. So what he said is that:
He is your father and always be your father whatever he is, but if things are like this as you mentioned in your question. Than he is no more muslim, he will be considered as murtid, as he is denouncing the PILLARS of Islam.
This being said, he is still your father and you have to be good with him in matters of the world. And you should try your best to get him back on track as he is your father and you will definitely not like him to burn in hell.
If you cannot do that and you fear staying with him will also make you rebellion to your beliefs than it is better for you to stay away. And still try with help of other peoples like people interested in TABLEEGH etc to get him back to the right path. Also make dua(pray) for him sincerely regularly.
May Allah guide him to the right path. Amen