# Should I ignore company of these people who are doing some particular sins, but not an extremist?

Tags: practical-islam, zina

Assalau'alaykum,

I often get confused about the thing that should I ignore company of these people who are doing some particular sins, but not an extremist?

As example, I dislike a close cousin of mine because she is an adulterer, but on the other hand she says good things about Islam, and praises about my practices. Another girl was my classmate who is very friendly, but lies a lot, adulterer (so far I got information, but I never claim these) and lied about me on my back, and whenever she is in front of me starts good speeches. So I was too much bothered, and started considering her as my enemy, and ignored her company as my best. Actually she did a lot on my back, and I stopped talking to her.

I have some few other friends, who are adulterer too, and also lies. but friendly with us, but it's true they can't be our well wisher. I do hate adultery, so often I ignore them, but became confused now that what should do according to Islam? Should I keep relation, and respect everyone (because we can't judge people in respect of their deeds, we don't know who is better than other), or should I ignore their company?

Somebody please enlighten me regarding this.

Jazakallah Khaier.

Comment: Maybe you may find my answer here helpful http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/33229/is-it-wrong-to-sever-ties-of-kinship-in-the-case-of-an-abusive-relative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alikom Assalam

Adultery is a great Sin, and the punishment is unbearable, this is one part of their torture in the grave (Al-barzakh):

> ... the Prophet (ﷺ) said, "In that oven there was much noise and voices." The Prophet (ﷺ) added, "We looked into it and found naked men and women, and behold, a flame of fire was reaching to them from underneath, and when it reached them, they cried loudly....
>   [Sahih al-Bukhari 7047](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/91/61)

And So is lying:

> ... Falsehood leads to Al-Fojur (i.e. wickedness, evil-doing), and Al-Fajur (wickedness) leads to the (Hell) Fire, and a man may keep on telling lies till he is written before Allah, a liar."
>   [Sahih al-Bukhari 6094](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/78/121)

You need to advise them and mention all that may help them realize the end of such sins, this is required as Islam is based on Muslims advising each other:

> It is narrated on the authority of Tamim ad-Dari that the Messenger of Allah (may peace and blessings be upon him) observed:
>   Al-Din is a name of sincerity and well wishing. Upon this we said: For whom? He replied: For Allah, His Book, His Messenger and for the leaders and the general Muslims.
>   [Sahih Muslim 55 a](https://sunnah.com/muslim/1/103)

You need to evaluate the situation, do they trust you, might they listen to you, are you the only person around them who might direct them to the righteous.

You also need to balance between being able to help them and to avoid any harm to yourself.

The other aspects related to your question are well answered in Medi1Saif's answer in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Salam,  Only constructive friendship will help you win this world and hereafter. Friends are to give us good advises,to be with us in our happiness and sadness. if they are not such friends you had better to leave them because they will get you like them and finally you will have to suffer hellfire.