# Obeying abusive parents?

Tags: parents, children

Assalamu Alaikum,

Since my early childhood my parents physically and emotionally abused me to the extent that I had mental issues. I was always faithful but under all the depression and confusion I couldnt practice my religion properly. After failed attempts of convincing them to stop I decided to move out a year ago and ever since my life became better. I am now praying 5 times a day and totally am devoted to Islam. My concern is: Am I allowed to avoid them out of fear that it would cause me to be disobedient to Allah again?

Comment: I asked a related question here: [Is it wrong to “sever ties of kinship” in the case of an abusive relative?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/33229/17163)  There, the notion of "gracious avoidance" was given as a possibility.

Comment: seems like a duplicate