# In what circumstance a Muslim can break the kinship?

Tags: fiqh, relationships, family

Asalaam Alikum

I want to know that in what circumstances a Muslim can break the Kinship.

- If a Sister leaves the home and marry against the will & in Absence of Moharram, Does the Family can break relation with her ?
- If a Family member or Relative Become Criminal (Thief, Bad Character, Murderer, Alcoholic, Drug Addict,Etc. Do we need to break relationship   with him/her
- Kindly Give me the Detailed Answer with reference in this regard.

with Regars

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. Please consider taking your time to make yourself familiar with our site and model by taking our [tour] and checking our [help]. This could be relevant [Is it wrong to sever ties of kinship in the case of an abusive relative](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/33229/is-it-wrong-to-sever-ties-of-kinship-in-the-case-of-an-abusive-relative/33300?)

Comment: It is not appropriate answer to my question

Comment: In what circumstance a Muslim can break the kinship?

Comment: I do disagree, your question might be opinion-based to a certain extent, but the answer is you can't by any means break the ties of kinship the only possible kind of break is al hajr al jameel (gracious avoidance) and this is addressed in the answer. The fact that the answer is hardly allowing to break the ties of kinship with a non-Muslim relative should be answer enough for your case.

Answer (score 1):

### In the name of God, the Merciful, the Most Kind

**All praise and thanks are due to God, the Lord of the worlds. We cannot find words to praise Him, as He only sees fit how laudation should be addressed to Him. We seek refuge in God from the evils within ourselves and the evils of our bad deeds. Whosoever God guides will never be led astray, and whosoever He leads astray will never find guidance. We bear witness that there is no god but God, the One without any associate, and We bear witness that Muhammad is His Messenger and bondman, peace and blessings be upon him, his kith and kin, his Companions and all those who follow their guidance until the Day of Judgment.**

---

**Q-1:** In what circumstances a Muslim can break the kinship?

Firstly, you should understand that in Islam, it is haram to break kinship and I find a **warning** for those who break kinship, because God Says:

> "But those who break the covenant of God after contracting it and sever that which God has ordered to be joined and spread corruption on earth - for them is the curse, and they will have the worst home." [**[The Thunder, 13:25](https://quran.com/13/25)**]

**Q-2:** If a Sister leaves the home and marry against the will & in Absence of Muharram, Does the Family can break relation with her ?

Secondly: it is not permissible for a man to marry a woman without the permission of her guardian, regardless of whether she is a virgin or previously-married. This is the view of the majority of scholars, including al-Shaafai, Maalik and Ahmad. They take as evidence the words of the Prophet (peace and blessings of God be upon him):

> "There should be no marriage contract except with a guardian"

**Q-3:** If a Family member or Relative Become Criminal (Thief, Bad Character, Murderer, Alcoholic, Drug Addict,Etc. Do we need to break relationship with him/her?

This is depends on the situation. One should protect his wife or her husband from that bad relative by keeping your spouse away from them unless your spouse can change them by advising them to stop. There is an authentic narration regarding this:

> It was narrated that Abu Sa‘eed al-Khudri (may Allah be pleased with him) said: I heard the Messenger of God (blessings and peace of God be upon him) say: “Whoever among you sees an evil action, let him change it with his hand (by taking action); if he cannot, then with his tongue (by speaking out); and if he cannot, then with his heart (by hating it and feeling it is wrong), and that is the weakest of faith.”
>
> Narrated by Muslim (49).

**Valid excuses for divorce are:**

> 1. Physical, mental, or emotional abuse or torture. When one of the spouses becomes abusive and inflicts physical, mental, or emotional torture, and is not willing to change by taking practical measures through therapy or counseling, then it is a valid reason for seeking divorce, for the Islamic principle states, **"There shall be no inflicting or receiving of harm.”** Injustice is not tolerated in Islam, regardless of who the perpetrator is.
> 2. Failure to fulfill the objectives and purposes for which marriage was initiated. This can be utter incompatibility between the partners, which may be expressed by their irreconcilable differences in temperaments, likes, and dislikes.
> 3. Marital infidelity. This can be a major cause for dissolution of marriage, for marriage is built on trust and confidence. Its main purpose is to preserve the chastity and modesty of those involved. Once this foundation is eroded and undermined and there is no chance to restore the same, then divorce is the way to go.
> 4. Failure of the husband to provide. When the man, who is considered the provider and maintainer of the family, fails to shoulder his responsibilities and the wife decides that she cannot continue tolerating his shirking of responsibility, this is grounds for divorce.

I have found a list of things which might help and might answers your question and worries and might be similar to your questions. Please view the following list:

1. [**Bad Relation between Husband & Wife By Mufti Menk, The Straight Path Convention Q&A**](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=IRZOy3dpQcw)
2. [**How to solve your Marital Issues ? Mufti Menk**](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=9L59ZXekecw)
3. [**Is it Haram to be around smokers and drinkers? - Q&A - Sh. Shady Alsuleiman**](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=8XV0898nDhQ)

I hope this answers all your questions.

**We ask God to guide us to the Straight Path and to make us all people of Paradise. May God send blessings and peace upon His slave and Messenger Muhammad and upon his family and companions.**

P.S. If there is anything you want to comment in order to be explained, then please feel free to comment below. And if you give a down vote, please explain and its reason to it so that I will understand.

---

**Sources:**

- [**How should she deal with her husband who drinks alcohol?**](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/145587/how-should-she-deal-with-her-husband-who-drinks-alcohol)
- [**Valid Reasons for Divorce**](https://archive.islamonline.net/?p=1228)
- [**Broken ties of kinship and relationships**](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/4631/broken-ties-of-kinship-and-relationships)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any circumstances where one is allowed to break the kinship.

I mean think about it. No breaks their kinship when things are all happy. People might tempt to break it when things go bad.

Islam's recommendation to not break the kinship is not about the happy times. You don't need a recommendation for that. It's about the bad times. The times you have a fight with your kin over money or some other quarrel, or at a time where your kin is doing something bad.

If you shun them out, then likely it will be end of the kinship. Potentially that person would also distance themselves from Islam. No one wants that.

If you open up, but also somehow silently let them know that you're not happy, e.g. be around, invite them to your house, but smile less to make them come forward and ask about why you're not happy.

A lot of times you have to let the person hit a wall, feel sorry about it and then come back to you. It's human nature.

Answer (score 0):

Salaam, what about if you're cousin has been prison for abusing his own daughter, can I break kinship with him when he comes out? My wife and sisters don't want anything to do with him and personally me too but i don't want to disobey Allah SWT.