# If one was bullied their whole life by all kinds of people, and has developed hatred towards those people, does Allah still blame him/her?

Tags: practical-islam, islamic-basis, behavior

If someone is really shy or quiet they are easy to get picked on by others. So if someone or a bunch of people who belittes you constantly for their own sense of humour amongst their friends, or excludes you a lot, and therefore you end up saying all these things out of your own build up of frustration and anger through your whole life about them, and talking bad words behind their backs, does Allah still blame the victim for this especially if they have been picked on their entire life?

Comment: I think [Is it wrong to sever the ties of kinship in the case of an abusive relative?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/33229/is-it-wrong-to-sever-ties-of-kinship-in-the-case-of-an-abusive-relative) has some relevance!

Answer (score 0):

ليس المؤمن بالطعان ولا باللعان

It means that we as believers should not say bad words or harm others by offending or damming them.
However, Allah says "والذين اذا أصابهم البغي هم ينتصرون" which gives a description to believers that if someone humiliates them or attacks them they give a defense and even punish the attackers. It is not about revenge but about being strong and preciously defend his religion.

People who offend you are only temporary , try to find good friends and company . If they really harm you and offend you do not be shy to escalate that to the manager or your parents (etc.). You do NOT have to live with it. They are wrong and they must change by all laws.

Answer (score 0):

In Surah Al-Nisa (The Women), the Qu'ran states:

> O Believers! Stand firm for justice as witnesses for Allah, even if it is against yourself, your parents, or close relatives. Be they rich or poor.

In other words, it is right to be angry against injustices when these occur against someone else, or some group or against yourself.

It is haram to allow this to develop into hatred. What is halal, is righteous anger and to stand up for justice.

And Allah knows best.