# Cutting ties with non muslim relatives?

Tags: non-muslim, kufr, family

Quran 9:23

> O you who have believed, do not take your fathers or your brothers as allies if they have preferred disbelief over belief. And whoever does so among you - then it is those who are the wrongdoers.

Does this mean we have to cut the relations with out non muslim relatives?

Comment: Seems relevant if not a duplicate of https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/33229/13438

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't mean to cut off with your relatives (especially with parents). You cannot cut off with your parents and other relatives until they compel you to obey or accept their religion. Allah clearly mentioned in [[Luqman 31:15](http://legacy.quran.com/31/15)]:

> "But if they (both) strive with you to make you join in worship with Me others that of which you have no knowledge, then obey them not; but behave with them in the world kindly, and follow the path of him who turns to Me in repentance and in obedience."

Read the following statement from [IslamQA](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/112006/how-should-a-muslim-deal-with-his-kaafir-family):

> The scholars of the Standing Committee for Issuing Fatwas were asked:
>   I have family who is mushrikeen (polytheists) except one sister who is a Muslim. Is it permissible for me to live and eat and drink with them, and if that is permissible so long as it is not at the expense of my religious commitment, then it is permissible for me to tell them frankly that they are kaafirs who are outside of the religion of Allaah? I have called them to Islam but they are hesitant, and they do not belong to this group or that, although they are closer to shirk, and I cannot find anywhere to live except with them.
>
> *They replied:*
>   What you must do is continue to advise them, remind them, keep good company with them, and speak gently to them. If you are wealthy, then spend on them, in the hope that Allaah may open their hearts and show them the light.

So finally, this doesn't mean to cut off with your relatives.

Comment: The standing committee can't be quoted in Tafseer ibn Kathir as there's a time gap of many centuries between both.

Comment: @husnainkazmi what about feeling love and affection towards them (assuming they are ok and dont object to family member being muslim). I seem to have read somewhere about Natural love and Religious love were we can love our non muslim relatives but dissawow their religion and the fact that Prophet S.A.W.S felt love towards his uncle who was a kaafir

Comment: @saintair we can have affection and love towards them of course. And you are saying right. We should love them so that they may revert toward Isalm. Don't hate them at all. In Islam, we are not prescribed to hate non-Muslims that do not interfere with your religious matters.

Comment: @husnainkazmi oh thanks. I was afraid about whether i can feel affection and love towards my family. My mother and sister and christian so i needed to know. By the way can you give me a tasfir of the ayah i posted? Is it in general or only when they are at war with muslims?

Comment: @saintair dear brother, read the Tafseer http://www.recitequran.com/tafsir/en.ibn-kathir/9:23 of the verse you have just quoted in the question. Brother, keep in mind you must have to respect, love and have great feelings about your family ( if they don't interfere against Islam). I've clearly mentioned the Quranic Verse in the answer. جزاک اللہ

Comment: Please take the time to cite your quotes properly. I would also recommend using less quotes in general; we encourage posts to be written in the author's own words based on an actual knowledge of the topic, not simply copied and pasted from other sites.